# Write a Google hangout chat bot on GAE. Where is the new com.google.appengine.api.xmpp?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

Back in the days, I wrote a simple XMPP base bot on GAE, and connect to it with Google Talk using com.google.appengine.api.xmpp

Now, that XMPP and GTalk are both retired, how can I build a bot which use Hangout chat to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in Hangouts functionality in GAE.

You need to use the Hangouts API which is javascript based.

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started